# Offsetting tuples in a nested list

Tags: python-2.7

Please how can I add offsets to a nested list of tuples and output as indicataed ie

```
ball = [[(2,0),(3,9)],[(7,4),(3,4)]]
offsets = [(50,50)]
```

how can I add the offsets, to have an output like this:

```
ball1 = [[(52,50),(53,59)],[(57,54),(53,54)]]
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do have a list within a list?

Comment: I have updated my answer seeing that you have lots of nesting in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
ball1 = ball[:]

for i,lst in enumerate(ball):
    for j,item in enumerate(lst):
        ball1[i][j] = (ball[i][j][0]+offsets[0][0], ball[i][j][1]+offsets[0][1])
```

Comment: @ederollora, I believe the OP has a set of lists within a list. Will update answer now. Thank you.

Comment: @ederollora, I just did. I am __sure__ this update works

Comment: @ederollora, Really appreciate that you were critical of my answer. No sarcasm (honestly). Thank you for pointing out my mistakes. :)

Comment: I think we should all try our code before posting but it's OK. Now works fine

Comment: @ederollora, You are absolutely right. Thank you again. :)